# Properties asymptotic analysis.

Tags: algorithm

When dealing with the analysis of time and space complexity of algorithms, is it safe to assume that any function which has tight bounds ( i.e. f(n)=Θ(g(n)) is asymptotically positive and asymptotically monotonically increasing,  n0 and c is taken as positive. What will happen if c is negative?

Comment: Are you asking if there are any algorithms that take a *negative amount of time* to execute?

Comment: according to the formal definition of Big Oh notation, "C" could only be a positive real number